How can I get this particular skinny arrowhead in tikz-cd?
I have seen many examples of texts using a particular type of tikzcd arrowhead. Here is an example:

Another example of these arrowheads can be found in Vakil's FOAG. How can I get such arrows?

On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a minimal working example (MWE): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I didn't think this would be a complicated thing to ask for. It's just changing an arrowhead style

If it isn't complicated, why don't you provide a test document so people don't have to do all the boring stuff, like choosing a class etc.

The diagram is made using the xy package. I'm not a big fan of the look of the arrow heads as it does not match the rest of the doc, so would not recommend trying to replicate.

In tikzcd, you can use the XY To tip specification of my answer A29704: XY To/.tip={To[length=+3pt +3.5, width=+2pt +2.5]}. There's even a XY To Tight tip specification. The first value with units specifies the base dimension, while the second value will be multiplied with the line width. Using both makes sure that the tip has a minimum size while still scaling with the line width.

@Qrrbrbirlbel that sounds like an answer

@Qrrbrbirlbel I'll accept that if you submit it as an answer

The package that create particular skinny arrowhead is xy: here there is also, for comparison, a diagram tikz-cd package.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}

\[
\xymatrix{
\cdots \ar[r] & A^{-2} \ar[r] \ar[d] & A^{-1} \ar[r] \ar[d] & A^{0} \ar[r] \ar[d] & A^{1} \ar[r] \ar[d] & A^{2} \ar[r] \ar[d] & \cdots \\
\cdots \ar[r] & B^{-2} \ar[r] & B^{-1} \ar[r] & B^{0} \ar[r] & B^{1} \ar[r] & B^{2} \ar[r] & \cdots
}
\]

\end{document}


\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
\cdots \arrow[r] & A^{-2} \arrow[r] \arrow[d] & A^{-1} \arrow[r] \arrow[d] & A^{0} \arrow[r] \arrow[d] & A^{1} \arrow[r] \arrow[d] & A^{2} \arrow[r] \arrow[d] & \cdots \\
\cdots \arrow[r] & B^{-2} \arrow[r] & B^{-1} \arrow[r] & B^{0} \arrow[r] & B^{1} \arrow[r] & B^{2} \arrow[r] & \cdots
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}

